# LeakActivity Leaked showing on Leak Canary

Tags: leakcanary

This activity is not part of my app and it keeps showing on Leak Canary app.

it doesnt even seems related to what activity i run and if i opened the app at all.

i got this message total of 6 times during last 12 hours

Can someone help to understand it?

````
LibraryLeak(className=leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakActivity, leakTrace=
┬
├─ android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    GC Root: System class
│    ↓ static ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder.sPool
│                                          ~~~~~
├─ android.util.Pools$SynchronizedPool
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ Pools$SynchronizedPool.mPool
│                             ~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[]
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ array Object[].[0]
│                     ~~~
├─ android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder.mRoot
│                                   ~~~~~
├─ android.widget.ListView
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    mContext instance of leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ ListView.mContext
╰→ leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakActivity
​     Leaking: YES (ListView↑ is leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is true and ObjectWatcher was watching this)
​     key = 53dca871-cc9b-4735-a0fd-98d21465fce0
​     watchDurationMillis = 14202
​     retainedDurationMillis = 9201
, retainedHeapByteSize=132349, pattern=instance field android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder#mRoot, description=In Android P, ViewLocationHolder has an mRoot field that is not cleared in its clear() method. Introduced in https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/86b326012813f09d8f1de7d6d26c986a909d Bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112792715)```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a know leak in the Android framework (ViewGroup.ViewLocationHolder) : https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/1081

LeakCanary actually identifies it as such, which is why it's reported as a "LibraryLeak". See that thread for ways to maybe fix it (it's hard because it's a bug in the android framework).

Comment: Thank you. Strange i could not find "LeakActivity Leaked" on google though.